# Vector spaces of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be the collection of polynomials $p(x)$, for which $p’(5)=0$.

1. State two polynomials that would belong to the set $W$.
2. State one polynomial that would not belong to the set $W$.
3. Is $W$ a subspace of a vector space containing all polynomial functions?
4. If the definition of the subset $W$ is changed to collection of polynomials $p(x)$, for which $p(5)=1$. Does that change your verdict about whether $W$ is a subspace or not.

For the first question I got $q_1(x):=1$ and $q_2(x):=-10x+x^2$ as the spanning set for $W$.
For the second question would it just be all polynomials not including the ones in the first question?
I’m not sure how you attack the last question. Thanks.

Comment: And what about the 3rd question?

Comment: Hint: Use the definition of a subspace.

Comment: Are you talking about polynomials of degree at most two?  If not, then why wouldn't a polynomial like $2x^3 - 15x^2$ be included in your spanning set?

Comment: The second part is incorrect, for example $x^3+x^2-85x$ is not in the subspace spanned by $q_1,q_2$ (please notice that $x$'s here are basis vectors of polynomial space, not scalars). Also for last part notice that $p(5)=1$ does not include the polynomial $p(x)=0$, therefore it is an affine (but not linear) space.

Comment: Careful for the second question.  Note for instance that $p_1+p_2$, i.e. $1 - 10x + x^2$, would also be an element of $W$